# Atomically swap pointers in C

Tags: c, atomic

I need threads to report a data structure living on the heap to a controlling thread (star topology). I wanted to not use locks for this but to do this by atomically swapping the pointer to this data structure. So I have a set and get method for the report.

```
static atomic_uintptr_t aptr = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT((uintptr_t)NULL);

void set_report(void *newreport)
{
    // swap the report pointer atomically
    uintptr_t prev = atomic_exchange( &aptr, (uintptr_t)newreport);
    // if prev is not NULL we need to destroy it
    if ( prev != (uintptr_t)NULL )
    {
        // destroy the memory it is pointing to
        free((void *)prev); //  there seems to be no way of avoiding a compiler warning here
                            //  about casting to a non-matching type :S
    }
}

uintptr_t get_report()
{
    // swap the report pointer atomically with NULL
    uintptr_t report = atomic_exchange( &aptr, (uintptr_t)NULL);
    // we now own report so the caller must destroy when finished with it
    // unless it's null of course
    return report;
}
```

I can use the code like this:

```
int *bla = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
*bla = 3;
set_report((void *)bla);

int *v = (int *)(void *)get_report();
```

I can hardly find any references or documentation about using the atomics with pointers so I have some questions about this code:

- Is this the right way to go when doing pointer swaps atomically in C
- From what I read I need to use uintptr_t when using the atomic methods for pointers (gcc stdatomic.h). But I can't get around the warnings about casting to non matching type. Should I just ignore those?
- Does 'aptr' need to be declared as volatile?

Comment: Pedantic: I suspect `(uintptr_t)NULL` needs to be `(uintptr_t)(void*)NULL` for maximum portability.

Comment: What warning do you get about non-matching type? I don't see any warnings with gcc using the flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: "right way to go when doing pointer swaps atomically in C" --> note that `uintptr_t` is an optional type.  Code may fail with function pointers, yet looks like only allocated pointers are used here.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: FYI - Questions about improvements to working code can also be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why casting NULL at all at `if ( prev != (uintptr_t)NULL )`?

Comment: Why don't you use the type `_Atomic void*` instead of `atomic_uintptr_t`?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Naked `NULL` is always a bit tricky given its type is not certain (could be `void *`, `int`, `long`, etc.).  `(void*)NULL` is certainly a _null pointer_.  An OP needs a `uintptr_t` version of a _null pointer_, not of `NULL`. Further, a _null pointer_ converted to `uintptr_t` is not certainly 0.  IAC, trying to do a pointer compare via `uintptr_t` conversions and then a integer math compare commonly "works" yet is not specified to do so as desired.  I suspect an `_Atomic void*` is the best approach and drop all the `uintptr_t` stuff.

Comment: Some answers to questions: The compiler warns when using `get_report`: `cast from function call of type 'uintptr_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to non-matching type 'void *'`

Comment: continued: The `atomic_uintptr_t` is in the stdlib. I'll have a try using `_Atomic (void *)` but I'd need to look into it if it is lock free. [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) is where some explanation is done. There are some macros for testing whether types are lockfree.